# Start Fragment before hand

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, design-patterns, android-viewpager

I have a parent fragment P which contains 10 buttons each on clicking will replace a container in P with child fragments C1 to C10. I should also be able to navigate from C1 to C2 on clicking next in action bar. I am able to achieve this but since each of the child fragment is having a heavy initialization (loading SVG, surfaceview etc..) the transition is not smooth. Is it possible to start the next fragment i.e. C2 when in C1 and put it in paused state so that it can be resumed directly when next in C1 is clicked.

This is someway similar to OffScreenLimit in ViewPager but when I have seen the view pager source code it doesn't replace the existing fragment but simply scroll the view to new fragment X.

Replacing the existing framework with ViewPager as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) is one possible solution but that requires a lot of changes with the existing code base and is the last thing I wish to do

Answer (score 0):

You can start all fragments when you create the activity, then just call it.

Do you know how to inicialize a `fragment`?

if not:

```
Fragment C1 = FragmentC1.newInstance();
Fragment C2 = FragmentC2.newInstance();
Fragment C3 = FragmentC3.newInstance();
...
```

Then when you click in a button just send the information wich one you want to open, do u know how to chenga fragment when you are in one?
Do you need the code for it?

Comment: I know how to initialize it. but will the above code bring the fragment to paused sate ? I want the fragment C2 to do all the pre-processing like reading the svg and converting into bitmap before hand and when I click the next in C1, C2 has to simply display the bitmap.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png

Check this image pls, and read the onCreate(); and onPause(); and onResume(); https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Please note that for the fragment lifecycle to start it has to be added to the activity in some way using the fragmentManager dynamically. By simply calling Fragment.newInstance lifecycle of the fragment won't get initiated

Comment: Please help if you know some way to start the lifecycle for C2 when you are still in C1 (You can't simply replace C1 and add C2 by calling `FragmentTransaction.replace(...)` )

Comment: Please read the question once again. It is not just simple fragment replace! I have read the link you provided and it doesn't help in this case

Comment: onCreate(); 
The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.
     just do c1.onCreate();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115942/discussion-between-revanth-gopi-and-francisco-melicias).